# Block access to an URL path by many IPs in .htaccess

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

I am only able to use `.htaccess` so `<Location>` and `<Directory>` are not possible.

I am currently using this to block access by IP:

```
<RequireAll>
  Require all granted
  Require not ip 1.0.132.75
  Require not ip 1.0.209.198
  Require not ip 1.0.209.229
  # ... many more IPs
```

I would like to block those many IPs only from accessing a certain path, namely a PHP login accessible at `/typo3/` / `/typo3/index.php`. But blocking everything under `/typo3` would be ok, too.

I could certainly use this but I hope that there is a shorter, more concise variant:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} "=1.0.132.75"
RewriteRule "^/typo3" "-" [F]
```

Well, now that I am writing it I found

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} "1\.0\.132\.75|1\.0\.132\.76|..."
RewriteRule "^/typo3" "-" [F]
```

but that Regular Expression would be very long (~3000 IPs). Probably there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible. I am leaving the question here for others to discover and add to it.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} "=1.0.132.75" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} "=1.0.132.76"
RewriteRule "^/typo3" "-" [F]
```